# Comment dire « n-tier » ou « multitier » en français ?

Tags: traduction, terminologie

Lorsqu'on parle d'architecture informatique, quelle est la bonne traduction de l'anglais *n-tier* (ou *[multitier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)*)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le [Grand Dictionnaire](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/btml/fra/r_motclef/index800_1.asp) (auquel on ne peut plus lier une page...) offre "architecture multiniveau" et "architecture n-niveaux" comme synonyme.

Comment: Il vaudrait mieux dire multiniveauX, ils sont plusieurs.

Comment: @M42 Pourquoi? On dit bien polyglotte au singulier.

Comment: @mouviciel: `polyglotte` est un adjectif, voir : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/polyglotte, `multiniveaux` signifie `avec plusieurs niveaux`

Comment: @M42 Tout comme *multinationalité* signifie "avec plusieurs nationalités" et ne s'écrit pas automatiquement avec un *S*. Ou *multifonctionnalité*, ou *multiprocesseur*...

Comment: @M42 Le Grand Dictionnaire ne met pas de X. Dans "Architecture multiniveau", multiniveau est aussi un adjectif. De plus, les mots suivants ont le même préfixe et ne se pluralisent pas d'eux mêmes: multicolore, multilingue, multijoueur, etc. (Dans le Petit Robert 2012). Si on parlait d'architectures, là on dirait multiniveaux.

Comment: Mais, étrangement, je viens de voir "architecture n-niveaux" comme synonyme. Dans ce cas, je crois que c'est vraiment une particularité du préfixe multi- qui fait que le mot ne se pluralise pass seul, mais bien avec son sujet.

Comment: Grâce au site [Liendex](http://ptaff.ca/liendex/), on peut faire un lien vers les résultats de recherche du cadre de gauche. Exemple : [architecture multiniveau](http://liendex.ptaff.ca/v2/fr_CA/francais/grand_dictionnaire_terminologique/architecture+multiniveau). L'utilisateur doit toujours choisir le domaine sémantique par contre.

Comment: Sur [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=multitier), on trouve aussi *multiniveau(x)* ainsi que *à plusieurs niveaux* et *à niveaux multiples*.

Comment: Au vu de tous ces commentaires, je pense que j'aurais mieux fait de poser une question séparée plutôt que de polluer celle-ci… Néanmoins merci à tous pour ces précisions.

Answer (score 4):

J'entends souvent

- [multi-tier](http://www.riff.org/definition_multi_tier_programmation)
- [n-tiers](http://medias.obs-mip.fr/www/Activite/Formation/Informatique/sgbd/cours013.html) (en particulier "[architecture trois tiers](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_trois_tiers)")
- [à N niveaux](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-serveur#Architecture_.C3.A0_N_niveaux)

Comment: Merci. C'est bon aussi de savoir ce qui est utilisé "pour vrai".

Comment: +1 J'utilise beaucoup ces termes en informatique. Ca me semble plus utilisé que *niveau.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Je suis d'accord, mais je ne pouvais pas négliger Wikipédia non plus.